# Retry connection with JMeter servers (generators) in JMeter Distributed setup

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

I've a distributed JMeter setup with 1 client (controller) and 2 servers (generators).

1. Now while a test is executing on the setup if a generator crashes in between, the controller gets hanged even after the test duration ends. [image: Hanged controller]
2. Is there a way to reconnect the controller with the generator after the generator comes up again during the same test execution?

Answer (score 1):

No there is no such configuration option and it is advised to restart servers.

Usually this is due to connectivity issues between server and controller like port not open.

For reference properties have a look at:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote

For 1/ you can add this to user.properties:

> client.continue_on_fail=true
> server.exitaftertest=true

Comment: Thanks @UBIK. What I understand then is that if this happens we should restart the test execution altogether. Also any insight on Ques 1? Can we prevent the controller hanging part, in case we want to continue with the remaining generators?

Comment: I updated answer, if ok you should accept it and upvote, thanks

Comment: Thanks @UBIK. I do get for point #2 but for #1 the controller still hangs after passing these attributes.